# SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis on create table statement

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I am getting

> SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

while executing below query in Oracle SQL Developer. Please suggest what's wrong:

```
 CREATE TABLE ARGUS_APP.TEMP_AST_FIX
    (
      CASE_NUM ARGUS_APP.CASE_MASTER.CASE_NUM%TYPE NOT NULL,
      CASE_ID ARGUS_APP.CASE_MASTER.CASE_ID%TYPE NOT NULL,
      EVENT_SEQ_NUM ARGUS_APP.CASE_EVENT_ASSESS.EVENT_SEQ_NUM%TYPE NOT NULL,
      PROD_SEQ_NUM ARGUS_APP.CASE_EVENT_ASSESS.PROD_SEQ_NUM%TYPE NOT NULL,
      DATASHEET_ID ARGUS_APP.CASE_EVENT_ASSESS.DATASHEET_ID%TYPE NOT NULL,
      LICENSE_ID ARGUS_APP.CASE_EVENT_ASSESS.LICENSE_ID%TYPE NOT NULL,
      SEQ_NUM ARGUS_APP.CASE_EVENT_ASSESS.SEQ_NUM%TYPE NOT NULL,
      DET_LISTEDNESS_ID ARGUS_APP.CASE_EVENT_ASSESS.DET_LISTEDNESS_ID%TYPE NOT NULL,
      UPDATE_TO_DET_LISTEDNESS_ID ARGUS_APP.CASE_EVENT_ASSESS.DET_LISTEDNESS_ID%TYPE NOT NULL,
      PROCESSED NUMBER(1) DEFAULT (0),
      PROCESSED_DATE DATE,
      CONSTRAINT PK_TEMP_AST_FIX PRIMARY KEY (CASE_NUM,CASE_ID, EVENT_SEQ_NUM, PROD_SEQ_NUM, DATASHEET_ID, LICENSE_ID, SEQ_NUM)
    );
```

I have checked all referenced Tables and Columns do exists with these names.

Comment: Data types of columns of a table need to be specified explicitly, not through `%TYPE` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table's columns have to be regular data types; you cannot reference another table's type.